# Proving that trivial solution implies column sum to 1 via contrapositivity

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

> Theorem: If A is a square matrix whose column sums are all equal to 1, then the equation AX=X has non - trivial solution.

Proof:

Suppose, by contrapositivity, that AX=X does not have non-trivial solution. This implies that the solution is trivial.
Indeed, AX=X IFF X = 0. 
From here, it suffices to show that the columns of A does not sum to 1.

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks in advance.